# Create a pivot table in SQL Server like the example below

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with columns primary key (int), date (datetime),  amount (int).

How can I create a pivot table like this?

[image: Example Pivot table]

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `grouping sets`?

```
select year(date), datepart(quarter, date), sum(amount)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (year(date), datepart(quarter, date)), (year(date)), () );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Aravs ACCEPTING the answer shows your appreciation for Gordon's time and talent.  It also acts as an indication to the other contributors that you have a solution.